# Windows forms calendar becomes slow when there are 5000 calendar items in it

Tags: c#, performance, unit-testing, calendar

I'm building an hour registration program with the use of a Windows calendar control. Now I have a question about the performance of this control when there are a lot of agenda items in it. 
I'm currently using this test code to populate the Calendar with 5000 calendar items:

```
 private void test()
        {
            Random r = new Random();

            int i = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
            {
                CalendarItem _calendaritem = new CalendarItem(calendar1);
                _calendaritem._activity = "activity" + i.ToString();
                _calendaritem._project = "project" + i.ToString();
                _calendaritem._client = "client" + i.ToString();
                _calendaritem.Text = "Title" + i.ToString();
                _calendaritem._price = r.Next(0, 200);
                _calendaritem._variouscosts = r.Next(0, 1000);
                _calendaritem._Kilprice = r.Next(0, 5);
                _calendaritem.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
                //_calendaritem.

                _calendaritem._note = "note" + i.ToString();

                DateTime _newdate = new DateTime(r.Next(2000, 2015), r.Next(1, 12), r.Next(1, 28));

                _calendaritem.StartDate = _newdate;
                _calendaritem.EndDate = _newdate.AddHours(5);

                _items.Add(_calendaritem);
            }

        }
```

The Calendar still works with this many items but the performance is really bad. The Calendar control becomes very slow.

Does anybody know what might cause this?

By the way there is one thing I think that might cause this problem and that is that the windows calendar uses a view range to load items only within that view. 
I tweaked this mechanism a bit because otherwise I could not save and open all the possible calendar item dates currently in the calendar control.

For example the place items method use to be like this:

```
private void PlaceItems()
        {
            foreach (CalendarItem item in _items)
            {
                if (calendar1.ViewIntersects(item))
                {
                    calendar1.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I use this code:

```
private void PlaceItems()
    {
        foreach (CalendarItem item in _items)
        {
            //if (calendar1.ViewIntersects(item))
            //{
            calendar1.Items.Add(item);

            //}
        }
    }
```

Are there work-arounds for this problem without losing the ability to save and open all the calendaritems in the calendar at ones?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fellow programmers I think I found the answer myself. 
If I use the place items method with the view intersect function (as it was before I edited it) it works fine also when there are more then 100.000 calendar items.

So I used to do the saving  by looping directly trough the calendar.item collection like this:

```
foreach (CalendarItem item in calendar1.Items)
                    {
                    }
```

That didn't work because then only the calendar items in the current view were saved. But If I do it like this all items are saved as planned and there are no performance declines:

```
     foreach (CalendarItem item in _items)
                {
                 }
```

So it works now!  I hope this answer will be useful to others who encounter the same problem.